# Routes only want a show on default despite explicit member statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, custom-routes

When I go to .. www.website.com/admin/organizations/org_deals , I get :

```
Missing template admin/organizations/show.erb in view path
```

My routes.rb :

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.napespace :organizations do |organization|
    organization.org_deals 'org_deals', :action => 'org_deals', :member => {org_deals => :get}
  end
end
```

In my rake routes :

```
 admin_organizations_org_deals        
/admin/organizations/org_deals
{:controller=>"admin/organizations/", :action=>"org_deals", :member=>{:org_deals=>:get}}
```

And last but not least. My file is in the directory :

```
/admin/organizations/org_deals.html.haml
```

But my app desperately wants a 'show'. How can I tell it, "no, no, no, what you really want is an org_deals, silly."

Thanks!

Comment: "When I go to .. www.website.com/admin/org_deals , I get :"

Did you mean "When I go to .. www.website.com/admin/organizations/org_deals"? If not, there's your problem...

Comment: Jamie Wong, sorry that was a typo. Should be the latter. I updated my post.

Comment: How about admin.namespace instead of admin.napespace?

Comment: Either way, what does your controller look like? If your controller has a show method, then rails is GOING to want to see a show.html.erb file at some point, if you're rendering HTML from it. Are you set up to be restful? If so, named routes get trixy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The :member key is reserved for using resources, it looks like it is expecting it as a parameter and is causing the route to not match and then to match to something else down the way.  I think if you remove the :member key, it will work.

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.napespace :organizations do |organization|
    organization.org_deals 'org_deals', :action => 'org_deals'
  end
end
```